# Node.js + Express not writing to file using FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a file that I am trying to write to from a post. Currently, the FS does not error nor does it write to file. However, when taking the same code from the deployed build and running it locally, it works. I even kept the file path consistent since it was throwing `no permissions error` at first. I ensured this file wrote to the same directory so each Filewrite Stream process would look at the same directory and file.
*Local build:*

```
var fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    var user_name = 'Password';
    var password = 'test';
    var errSTR = ""
    fs.writeFile('C:\\hi.txt', 'Content to write', { flag: 'w' }, function(err) {
        if (err) 
            return console.error(err); 
      fs.readFile('C:\\hi.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err);
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
```

*Deployed Build:*

```
app.route('/test')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.send('GET test');
    })
    .post(function(req, res) { // Start Post
      var boolTry = false;
      try {
        boolTry = true;
        var bool = false
        var user_name = "Password"//req.body.user;
        var password = "test"//req.body.password;
        var errSTR = ""
        fs.writeFile('C:\\hi.txt', user_name + password, { flag: 'w' }, function(err) {
          if (err) 
              return console.error(err); 
          fs.readFile('C:\\hi.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                return console.error(err);
            res.send(500 + err);
            console.log(data);
          });
        })
      } catch (error) {
        bool = true
        errSTR = error
      }
      res.send('POST test' + " " + boolTry + " " + bool + " " + errSTR +  ";")
    })//END POST
    .put(function(req, res) {
      res.send('PUT test');
    });
```

The local build will properly write to the file, while the dev build appears to do nothing. It should be noted by booleans were being used to understand how the file writer works but here is the server response from build: `successful response POST test true false ;`

**Using:**

```
 IISNODE for iis: 7.x
 Express: 4.16.2
 node.js: v8.9.4
 cors: 2.8.4
 body-parser: 1.17.2
```

*Sidenote*: If you are confused by the writing portion of code, the intention was to write, check error then read, check error for assurance.

**Update**
Reoccurring error based on certain filewrite methods Error: `EPERM: operation not permitted, open`. Yes, all permissions for the directory are enabled along with ensuring read and write are checked.

Comment: `return console.error(err);` why aren't you throwing the error to be caught in the catch?

Comment: Great question, I was not sure which to use. However, when I use `throw new Error(err);` it has no effect. So I left it as is. If you believe this is more proper however, please let me know! @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: I think it could be a cause since `console.error` doesn't appear to throw an error, just prints to the console [according to the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error).  If you want to log the error, it should be done in your catch block.  Try `throw err;` instead since it's already an exception object.

Comment: If you utilize the `*Sync` methods, they will throw errors instead of having to handle them.

Comment: After trying `fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '../routes/uploads/hi.txt'), user_name + password, { flag: 'w' }, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }` this appears to do nothing as well. @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1After adding sync `successful response POST test true true Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Services\RATS2-DATA-VIEWER-WEB-SERVICE\api\routes\uploads\hi.txt' C:\Services\RATS2-DATA-VIEWER-WEB-SERVICE\api\routes\uploads\hi.txt;` with `fs.writeFileSync('C:\\hi.txt', 'Content to write', { flag: 'w' });` so this is the same problem I was dealing with the first time, but I forgot how I got rid of it. Think it was adding the flag: w